# How to change where a symlink points

Tags: files, symlink

[image: Screenshot of terminal with symbolic link]

Can you tell me what this is in the area marked red?

If I want to change `/media/files/tb-prod/files` to some other path, how would I do that?

Comment: yea.. but i didnt know about symbolic link before thats why i added screenshot to someone help. and @michael homer answered me for that.

Comment: The other question should be marked as a duplicate of this one. This one is more useful.

Answer (score 513, accepted):

`files` is a [symbolic link](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_381) to `/media/files/tb-prod/files`. When you access `files` or anything inside it, you'll really access the path under `/media`. Symbolic links are made and updated using the [`ln` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ln.html). This link could have been made with:

```
ln -s /media/files/tb-prod/files files
```

`-s` means to make a symbolic link. To update a link, either delete the link and create it as above, or use the `-f` option to `ln` as well. If you are linking to a folder, you should include the `-n` option:

```
ln -sfn /a/new/path files
```

This will replace the link with a new one pointing at `/a/new/path`.

The `-n` option is necessary when linking to a different target folder to avoid creating a sub-folder inside the old target folder `files` and instead replace the symbolic link completely.

Comment: Example how to delete the symlink would be good

Comment: @AndrewAtkinson: you delete a symlink as if it's a normal file, with `rm /path/to/symlink`.

Comment: I don't understand what the `-n` does, even after reading the man page. linking to symlinks of directories seems to work without it.. Anyone know?

Comment: @naught101 It's not for linking to directories, it's for replacing links to directories instead of making a new link inside the directory.

Comment: @MichaelHomer AHHH!! I HATE that default behaviour. `-n` is something I've been wanting for ages! Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @naught101 The default behavior is useful, but that's personal opinion I guess.  It has been a *gotcha* for me too before getting used to it.