# How to view MATLAB livescripts?

Tags: symlink, manjaro, matlab

When I try to open a matlab livescript inside the default DE, I get an error that says:

> Viewing MATLAB Live Script files is not currently supported by this operating system configuration. For more information, see the documentation.

It also includes a link to the "Unsupported Features" section of the livescript documentation which however does not say anything about this particular problem as far as I can see.

The [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Matlab#Live_Script_Errors) does have information on my problem though (I am running Manjaro xfce). It says there that as a possible workaround for my problem I would have to point MATLAB shipping glib libraries to those glib libraries from my system and that I would have to change the following symlinks to do this:

```
libgio-2.0.so
libglib-2.0.so
libgmodule-2.0.so
libgobject-2.0.so
libgthread-2.0.so
```

I found this [answered question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151999/how-to-change-where-a-symlink-points?rq=1)  on this SE that shows how to change symlinks, but I don't know where to point them exactly.

My questions are: where are system glib libraries usually located and how would I then proceed to update my symlinks to the correct location?

Comment: I figured it out, i had to use ln -sfn targetpath symlinkpath with absolute paths. the files to link to were located in /usr/lib/ and i had to link an additional library like the wiki says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

In my case, the files to link to were located in `/usr/lib/`.
Using `ln -sfn /target/path /sym/link/path` (with absolute paths!), i was able to link them to the proper files. In addition, I installed a library as pointed out [in the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Matlab#Live_Script_Errors), namely `gconf`.